# `sed` pattern matching?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, command

```
Permissions   links  Owner  Group  Size   Date        Time    Directory or file
-rwxr--r--     1     User1  root    26    2012-04-12  19:51    MyFile.txt
drwxrwxr-x     3     User2  csstf  4096   2012-03-15  00:12     MyDir
```

I have problem for pattern match to get certain details using the above details. I actually need to write down the shell script to get the following details. 
I need to use pipe in this question. When I do `ls -la | prog.sh` it need to show the details below. 
 
The major part I don't get is how to use `sed` pattern matching. 
1. Total number of lines read. 
2. Total number of different users (owners). 
3. Total number of files with execute permission for the owner. 
4. The top 3 largest directory. 
This is what I have tried so far

```
#!/bin/bash
while read j

    do 

        B=`sed -n '$=' $1`
        echo "total number of lines read = $B"



done
```

Comment: @hek2mgl above shows. Very few I have done

Comment: Looking at your numbered list, I would bet it's faster to write the `ls` output to a file and then `grep`ing, `awk`ing (or `cut`ing), `uniq`ing (`-c`) and `sort`ing the data out of it. Sorry for the many `ing`s :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop reads the output of `ls -la` line by line and you need to process each line and maintain variables for the information you need.

Here is a sample script to get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i lineCount=0
declare -i executePermissionCount=0

# an array to keep track of owners
declare -a owners=()


# read each line into an array called lineFields
while read -r -a lineFields
do
    # the owner is the third element in the array
    owner="${lineFields[2]}"

    # check if we have already seen this owner before
    found=false
    for i in "${owners[@]}"
    do
        if [[ $i == $owner ]]
        then
            found=true
        fi
    done

    # if we haven't seen this owner, add it to the array
    if ! $found
    then
        owners+=( "$owner" )
    fi


    # check if this file has owner execute permission
    permission="${lineFields[0]}"
    # the 4th character should be x
    if [[ ${permission:3:1} == "x" ]]
    then
        (( executePermissionCount++ ))
    fi

    # increment line count
    (( lineCount++ ))
done
echo "Number of lines: $lineCount"
echo "Number of different owners: ${#owners[@]}"
echo "Number of files with execute permission: $executePermissionCount"
```

Comment: `sed` isn't appropriate here because you are doing line-by-line processing.